# Import Multiple Spredsheets into 1 - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I am new to all things VBA and have created some very basic Macros. This one I need help with.

My current work has a situation where processors will have their own file, and data in column A and B only, and each new date is a new tab.

I need to create a master file that pulls in all the data on the previous days tab from each individual (stored in their own folders). During the import I simply need to add the data to A and B on the Master sheet at the next available cell each time (To prevent blanks)

Is this do able?

I wrote the following that allows a user to open each file and select the range to be imported and then it does the import, but I need it all automated and driven by the date on the tab.

Also the file names are the same for each worker, nested in a folder with their name. The file name changes with the month.

```
Sub ClickToImport()
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xWb.Activate
        'Set xRng2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        Set xRng2 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        xRng1.Copy xRng2
        xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        xAddWb.Close False
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
Sub TryThis()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A3")

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Select
    s = cell.Value
    strFile = Dir(s & "*.xlsx")

    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open(s & strFile)

Next cell

End Sub
```

My worksheet setup is like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
'I defined the next blank row in order to add the rows of data into the Master Sheet.
'Please see below

Sub ClickToImport()
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Dim NextBlankRow As Long
NextBlankRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1

Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Choose Your File"
    .Show
If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Type:=8)
        xWb.Activate
        Set xRng2 = Range("A" & NextBlankRow)
        xRng1.Copy xRng2
        xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        xAddWb.Close False
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way to automate the file selection and import so it’s completely hands off.

Comment: To automate the file selection, you have to specify the path of the file. The path should be the same each time. Will the range for the data that you are selecting be the same each time?

Comment: The path will be the same, but files are in 10 different folders. One for each employee. All named for the current month

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge data from all sheets into one single master sheet, right.

'Fill in the range that you want to copy
Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

As an aside, you can try the AddIn from the URL below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]

Comment: This looks great, but do I have to have all the worksheets open? I want to execute this from the master without having to open each individual sheet.

Comment: On your sample code, where do I indicate where all the files are?